# Is there a way to change 3 finger drag to 4 finger drag

Tags: macos, trackpad, bettertouchtool

Is there a way of using third party software like Better Touch Tool to configure a 4 finger dragging gesture?

I want to reserve 3 finger gestures for many other actions.

Answer (score 1):

In Better Touch Tool, I find these four-finger gestures... No four-finger drag, I guess.

[image: threefinger]

But to be sure you could try asking at http://blog.boastr.net/what-is-bettertouchtool/